# magento 2 : where is Layout XML File for Homepage located

Tags: magento2, layout, xml, home-page

`\vendor\magento\module-catalog\view\frontend\layout\catalog_product_view.xml`
is the layout xml file for Product Detail Page.

Where are the layout xml files for **Homepage** and for **Category Page** (page that shows after clicking on a category link ex. 'http://127.0.0.1/magento/category-1.html', where layered navigation is displayed) ?

what I mean by **Catgory Page**:
[image]

thanks

Comment: hello @Blackpanther0001,  how did you change your header style, my stylesheet is not showing up in the source files. can you help me?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Magento-2 file path hierarchy

> First check in your current theme

```
app/design/frontend/YourTheme/ThemePackage/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_category_view.xml
app/design/frontend/YourTheme/ThemePackage/Magento_Cms/cms_index_index.xml
```

> Second check in your current theme parent theme.

```
app/design/frontend/CurrentParentTheme/ThemePackage/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_category_view.xml
app/design/frontend/CurrentParentTheme/ThemePackage/Magento_Cms/cms_index_index.xml
```

> Third check in core module.

```
vendor/magento/module-cms/view/frontend/layout/cms_index_index.xml
vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/layout/catalog_category_view.xml
```

For home page you have to check in current assign home page

> Admin >> Content >> Pages >> Selecte your current home page.

Check home page content and  Layout Update XML in Design tab.

Comment: Please keep in mind cms_index_index.xml does not cover the homepage if you navigate with /home at the end of the url! Magento will handle the page as `cms-page-view` not as `cms-index-index`

Answer (score 1):

The homepage is `vendor/magento/module-cms/view/frontend/layout/cms_index_index.xml`. Category page is `vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/layout/catalog_category_view.xml`.

Answer (score 0):

Remove all content from `default.xml` that should be displayed on the homepage, `content` region, e.g. all of your custom blocks.

Then create a file called `cms_index_index.xml` in the same place where your `default.xml` lives, with the following content:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * cms_index_index.xml
 *
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 * 
 * This file only is displayed on the homepage of magento
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">

    <referenceContainer name="content">
        <!-- Insert your blocks just for the homepage here, e.g. -->
        <container htmlTag="section" htmlClass="widget block block-static-block newsletter-block">
            <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Widget\Block" name="newsletter" template="Magento_Theme::html/subscribe.phtml">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">newsletter</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
        </container>
        <container htmlTag="section" htmlClass="widget block block-static-block view-catalogue-block">
            <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Widget\Block" name="view_catalogue" template="Magento_Theme::html/view-catalogue.phtml">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">view_catalogue</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
        </container>

        </referenceContainer>

    <body/>
</page>
```

Tested on Magento 2.2